Azure Copy Activity issue
My project has Maria DB as on-prem source system, it is connected with ADF via Self hosted integration runtime. I want to copy only the required fields from 100 tables of MariaDB to Data Lake but I want to make sure that the query is executed on Maria DB and not on Azure side due to strict data policies of my organization. Is there any way to achieve this? I read that if we execute the SQL query in copy activity, it is staged in Azure via SHIR which means it goes through organization network and firewall which I dont want.
I created a copy activity, provided all the details of source environment - MariaDB and observed that it has preview data section which will defeat the purpose of bringing only the required fields into Azure as I can see all the columns in preview section

If you use the "query" option and provide an SQL query with only the required columns, ADF will only copy those columns and only show them in preview.


I read that if we execute the SQL query in a copy activity, it is staged in Azure via SHIR, which means it goes through the organization's network and firewall, which I don't want.

Without using an SQL query, you can use the workaround below if you have the same columns in all tables:
After providing a list of tables for the "for-each" activity, create a dataset parameter on the source side for the table name. Go to the mapping tab and import the schema by giving one table name to the dataset parameter, as shown below:

Select the required fields from the schema, as shown below:

After debugging the pipeline, the required tables with selected fields will successfully copy to the data lake.

@user25175650 Check if above provided solution works for you?
